# What's the size of virtual memory of the Linux kernel occupies in a 48GB memory, 64-bit machine?

Tags: linux, memory

What's the size of virtual memory of the Linux kernel occupies in a 48GB memory, 64-bit machine? I know in a 32-bit machine, the Linux kernel occupies 1GB virtual memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a configurable value. Most probably it takes as much as there is available [swap space](http://superuser.com/questions/172724/what-file-system-is-swap-on-linux)

Comment: why would care about the swap when you have 48GB RAM? (just kidding)

Comment: @KurzedMetal: It's a valid concern, which is irrespective of the actual RAM installed. For example, you might want to memory map a 100GB file. Hey, don't ask me why, but you might want to do that :-)   This "just works" like magic. Except when your available address space is only 2GB, it doesn't... so it may make sense to ask. Imagine a defragmenter that mmaps the drive and moves sectors with memcpy ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD64 uses addresses of "canonical form" (see pages 131-135 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120617135759/http://support.amd.com/us/Embedded_TechDocs/24593.pdf)) for implementations that do not implement the full 64 bits. The rationale behind this weird scheme is that it is possible to add more bits in the future as hardware evolves, and the two halves will grow together towards the middle.

Currently, **all** implementations (i.e. all existing processors) have 48 bit addresses, thus 00000000'00000000--00007FFF'FFFFFFFF, and FFFF8000'00000000--FFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF are valid address ranges, with 128TB of memory in each half of the usable address space (256TB total).

So that would be 128TB, which is also the maximum per-process address space under Linux [under AMD64](http://www.debian.org/ports/amd64/).